# Why does std::max return the wrong value?

Tags: c++

In the "[Grill the Committee](http://youtu.be/7P536lci5po?t=1h18m13s)" session from CppCon 2014, Committee member Walter Brown mentioned that std::max returns the wrong value in the case that both arguments have an equal value.

This was accepted without comment, and not elaborated upon.  What did he mean by this?  Why should it matter which value is returned?

Comment: IIRC for some ordering arguments it makes more sense to return the second argument in the case where both are equal.

Comment: @juanchopanza Interesting, could you please show an example ? Thanks!

Comment: That comes (I believe) from Alexander Stepanov's "Notes on Programming" - probably has a rationale in there.

Comment: @P0W I found [these notes from Stepanov](http://www.stepanovpapers.com/notes.pdf). I think he also covers this in "elements of programming".

Comment: Perhaps it hase something to do with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order#Strict_total_order

Comment: I can't think of a scenario in which that could effectively be considered a problem although the issue is more or less clear

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If `min` and `max` are only used on ordered sets, all reasonable definitions are equivalent.

In practice, however, `min` and `max` are used on preordered sets: sets in which you can have two elements that sort the same without being identical.  For example, you could be manipulating:

```
struct student {
    char *name;
    int grade;
};
```

and define `s1 < s2` when `strcmp(s1->name, s2->name) < 0`.  Then two students with the same name but different grades will sort the same.  Such two elements are said to be *equivalent* for the (pre)ordering relation.

On a preordered set, the argument goes, `min` of two equivalent elements should return the first parameter, and `max` should return the second.  This definition preserves a few properties that you'd expect, most notably

- the pair (`min(x,y)`, `max(x,y)`) is either (`x`,`y`) or (`y`,`x`),

and

- if `x` and `y` are distinct, then `min(x,y)` and `max(x,y)` are distinct,

and

- the function that maps (`x`,`y`) to (`min(x,y)`, `max(x,y)`) is a stable sorting function for sets of two elements.

This is not a new idea, and you'll find way better explanations than mine in a number of standard texts on programming.  Chapter 7 of the [Stepanov Papers](http://www.stepanovpapers.com/notes.pdf), already cited by Mat and juanchopanza, is a good source if you like C++ syntax.

Comment: I think we can have a function `std::stable_max` (and for consistency `std::stable_min`) to solve this incosistency.